# WindowBuilder Change Orientation of Menu Dropdown

Tags: java, menu, swt, windowbuilder

I cannot seem to find the option to change this variable in WindowBuilder at all. In the preview the orientation is fine...

[image: WindowBuilder Preview]

But when I run the program I get this...

[image: Running Program]

Notice how it goes right to left instead of left to right like most programs do.

I cannot find where to change this anywhere in the SWT documentation.  Can anyone please point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Comment: SWT doesn't have anything to control this. This is something that the operating system's menu manager chooses to do depending on the position of the menu.

Comment: That... doesn't seem right.  You should be able to control how your GUI window looks and not just have the OS handle it.

Comment: @snowfi6916 That's exactly what SWT was designed to do, though... Look like a native app. Consequently, it uses native controls and can't change their behaviour except for options that the OS provides. If you want more control, you'll have create your own controls or switch to a different framework.